# How to recursively list only video file types and exclude some folders ? in Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

I have a lot of internal HDDs, with video files spread a bit all over the place.

I would like to be able to list all the video files (*.avi *.mp4 *.wmv...) in DIRs and SUBDIRs, while also *excluding* some folders from the listing, and outputting the results to a file.

I have tried using:

`dir "D:\Mini Clips Series" *.avi *.mp4 *.wmv  /b /s /a-d >> E:\Temp\List.txt`

and variants thereof. The main problem being that specifying several file types doesn't seem to be compatible with the /s switch...

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with the `/R` (recurse) switch, passing your extensions as a set.

```
for /R "D:\Mini Clips Series" %i in (*.avi *.mp4 *.wav) do dir /b %i >> "E:\Temp\List.txt"
```

The `/R` switch recurses sub folders as well, so you don't need the `/s` on the `dir` command, as you can see.  (I didn't bother with the `/a-d`, but you should still be able to use it.)

If there's an existing "E:\Temp\List.txt", you'll want to delete it first, as the above will append to (not overwrite) that file (the `>>` redirection instead of `>`). If you don't want to have to do that, you can use this instead:

```
del "E:\Temp\List.txt" & for /R "D:\Mini Clips Series" %i in (*.avi *.mp4 *.wav) do dir /b %i >> "E:\Temp\List.txt"
```

The `&` allows both commands to be on the same command line. The `del` is done first, followed by the `for` loop.

You can find out more about the `for` command by typing `for /` from a command prompt.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick and helpful reply. There's a small issue that I haven't been able to solve yet. It generates a "  1" character that prevents piping to the List.txt file.
The resulting command is something like dir /b D:\Mini Clips Series\Cat_door.mp4   1>>"D:\List.txt". Resulting in the error msg: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Spip: I tested both command lines on my machine, and didn't have any issue at all. I reviewed the text file afterward as well, and it was fine and contained the correct files. The only things different in my tests were the two folder names. Did you copy/paste the code directly from my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have copy / pasted the 1st command directly, and also used a slight variation for use in a batch file (for /R "D:\Mini Clips Series" %%i in (*.avi *.mp4 *.wmv) do dir /b /a-d %%i >> "D:\List.txt"). Both with a weird "  1" character generated right before the >>

Comment: @Spip: Strange. What Windows version are you using? I tested on Windows 10 Version 1909 according to WinVer.exe, and I'm not seeing that at all on either version.

Comment: @Spip Win7 has been end-of-lifed by MS, so I don't have anything that's using it to try to help any further. Sorry. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few tries, finally found a batch script that works under Win7.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET test="D:\Mini Clips Series"
FOR /R %test% %%F IN (*.avi *.mp4 *.wmv) DO (
ECHO %%F >> List.txt)
```

It outputs all corresponding filenames with their full path (similar to dir /b /a-d), recursively (/s).

Thanks again for the helpful replies.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using Grep? There are various Windows binaries for it and you could off-load the filtering from 'dir' to grep.

```
dir "folder" /S | grep "regex" > list.txt
```